# Use of "Listen" in Socket Server in C++ Using Linux

Tags: c++, sockets, socketserver

In my socket server code, it is written that:

```
listen (socket_fd, 5);
```

I know this is written here for the reason of "listening connection" but I am not sure what the parameter 5 means. Also is there any syntax

```
 socklen_t
```

I tried to find it using manual command but was unable.

Comment: Regarding the first question, the [**man page**](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen) is pretty clear, It is the size of the pending connection backlog before issuing refusals. Note that is **not** *concurrent* connections. It is the backlog size of connecting clients waiting for an `accept()`.

Comment: @WhozChraig, so I will allow maximum 5 pending connection in my queue, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this site](http://www.on-time.com/rtos-32-docs/rtip-32/reference-manual/socket-api/listen.htm), the second parameter is the backlog queue size.  The `listen(int fd, int size)` function creates a queue for incoming connection requests.  So in your example you would be able to handle five connection attempts that arrive at (or very close to) the same time.

Comment: Or five attempts that arrive years apart, if it took you years to get around to calling `accept()` again. Time has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter is a *hint* to the kernel about the size of the backlog queue. This is a queue of connections which have been completed by TCP but not yet returned as sockets by `accept()` in the application (because the application may be slow calling `accept()`). The kernel is free to adjust the hint up or down. In practice, backlogs as low as five haven't been seen for years if not decades.